# SCNScene - fatal error calling SCNScene(named:): Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm using a shared project and have spent a lot of time updated it to Swift 2 so I'd like to get this working but unfortunately I have a runtime error to contend with. The storyboard has nothing on it so everything is done programatically. Seeing that it's done programatically I'm not sure why I'm getting this runtime error.

Please tell me what "glasses1.dae" and "glasses2" are in this code. What identifiers are these?

> function signature specialization  of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
>
> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)
>
> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION ...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
private let notificationCenter : NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

private let screenWidth : CGFloat = 320
private let scaleX : CGFloat = (320 / 750)
private let scaleY : CGFloat = (568 / 1334)

private let eyeRectL : UILabel = UILabel()
private let eyeRectR : UILabel = UILabel()

private var scnView : SCNView!
private var glasses : SCNNode!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Scene
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "glasses1.dae")! // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 

    // Camera
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    // Light
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    // Ambient Light
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    glasses = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("glasses2", recursively: true)! // what is "glasses2"?

    scnView =  SCNView()
    scnView.scene = scene
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    scnView.frame = self.view.bounds

    let moohaha = setupMoohaha()
    let cameraView = visage.moohahaCameraView

    self.view.addSubview(cameraView)
    self.view.addSubview(scnView)

    self.view.addSubview(eyeRectL)
    self.view.addSubview(eyeRectR)

    moohaha.beginFaceDetection()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `.dae` file contains scene information and is used to load a scene created externally (not in code).  That "glasses1.dae" string is the name of a file that should be part of your project.  Presumably the `childWithNodeName(_:recursively:)` method call is used to find a child node with the name "glasses2" that is created as part of the scene defined in the `.dea` file used to create the scene.

The `!` operator at the end of the two lines you are indicating is used to force unwrap an optional value, and it will crash the program if the value contains `nil`.  As such, I assume that your scene is not being created because the "glasses.dea" file is not actually part of your project and SceneKit is failing to load it and returning a `nil` scene.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I know what optionals :) I just meant why was i getting that error. I guess I'm on a mission for the mysterious dae file. As a side note, could I delete those references and just use the camera? What could I delete safely? Any scene code?

Comment: I would need more knowledge of the app to answer that question.  It depends on if anything was actually in the dea file or not.  I assume it has content that is important, so you can't just omit it.

Comment: Well it appears the glasses are a 3D glasses overlay. Not sure why the scene wasn't in the Git. I just commented the related scene code and the app works. I can at least test the algorithm etc.

Comment: Apparently someone needs to learn how to check in their files correctly. :>

Comment: I was just making a joke about the original author not knowing how to use git.

Comment: oh yeah lol. Swoosh, right over my head. Or maybe he's one of those guys who shares all but the key cool ingredient lol The rest of us limping off the stage :)